# Regarding finiteness of the limit of sums

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity

Let $U$ be an domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $\alpha:U\times U\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function with the property that $\alpha(z,w)=\alpha(w,z)$ for all $z,w\in U$ and $\alpha(z,w)\leq \alpha(z,v)+ \alpha(v,z)$ for all  $z,w,v\in U$.

We are given a piecewise smooth path $\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow U$. Where $\gamma(a)=z$ and $\gamma(b)=w$. Take a partition $a=x_0\leq x_1 \leq x_2\cdots\leq x_n=b$. Then choose finer and finer partitions satisfying $\sup_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i-x_{i-1}=\Delta\longrightarrow 0$.

Now define $L_\alpha(\gamma)=\lim_{\Delta\longrightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha(\gamma(x_i),\gamma(x_{i-1}))$.

It is said the by the continuity of $\gamma$, $L_\alpha$ is well defined. I know that for every finite partition the sum is finite, but why will the limit be finite?

Answer (score 1):

The limit can be infinite even when $\gamma$ is the identity map. Indeed, let $n=1$, $U=\{z\in \Bbb C:|z|\le 1\}$, and $\alpha(z,w)=\sqrt{|z-w|}$ for all $z,w\in U$. Let $a=-1$, $b=1$ and $\gamma(x)=x$ for each $x\in [-1,1]$. Given $n$, for each $i\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ put $x_i=2i/n-1$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha(\gamma(x_i),\gamma(x_{i-1}))=\sqrt{2n},$ that tends to infinity when $n$ tends to infinity.